# Use generics to define return value for function with discriminated union as input

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that receives an object with `updatedAt` and/or `createdAt` properties (as a Date) and returns the same object but with the single or both values serialized as a string.

First of all, how do I define this function's return type?

Second, I have a feeling that this is better done with generics, but I haven't found the correct way to do it that way.

This is what I currently have:

```
type HasBothValues = {
  [key: string]: any;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
};

type HasCreatedAt = {
  [key: string]: any;
  createdAt: Date;
};

type HasUpdatedAt = {
  [key: string]: any;
  updatedAt: Date;
};

type AllInputVariants = HasBothValues | HasCreatedAt | HasUpdatedAt;

const serializeDates = (obj: AllInputVariants): any => { //  <-- Don't like the any return type!
  const retObj = { ...obj };
  if (obj.createdAt) {
    retObj.createdAt = obj.createdAt.toISOString();
  }

  if (obj.updatedAt) {
    retObj.updatedAt = obj.updatedAt.toISOString();
  }

  return obj;
};

export { serializeDates };
```

I appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function overloading seems to be a good solution here.

First we create a type called `Overwrite` to change the types of some properties.

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U extends infer O ? {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K]
} : never
```

Now we can add all possible function overloads:

```
function serializeDates<T extends HasBothValues>(obj: T): Overwrite<T, {updatedAt: string, createdAt: string}>
function serializeDates<T extends HasUpdatedAt>(obj: T): Overwrite<T, {updatedAt: string}>
function serializeDates<T extends HasCreatedAt>(obj: T): Overwrite<T, {createdAt: string}>
function serializeDates<T extends AllInputVariants>(obj: T) { 
  const retObj: any = { ...obj };
  if (obj.createdAt) {
    retObj.createdAt = obj.createdAt.toISOString();
  }

  if (obj.updatedAt) {
    retObj.updatedAt = obj.updatedAt.toISOString();
  }

  return retObj;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwEIHtgAsBqcA2BXCBKAXigG8AoKKAbQGsIQAuKBYAJwEsA7AcwF0WcbiADcVKAGN2EOMAgATAILAWAETkRx1PGAWblqqBvniAvuIqhIsRAGEZBlSXIT6jFmy59BUYWIlpWXlDdU1zS2toeAQAVT0nYBdKandmVg4eASERbShdfRCVMNMKCworcGglHBwASW4wPGBsLmFgIlIY1AxsfEIoAB9bBAdgxWdhmPjCieBIqqgAeQA3CHYAdy55AB4AFQAaKFiAPhcABU5JOn2jgFEAD0l8BQgdhhAUADMoQ6gP77HE5nABkxygEAe8m4CiIPC+62WUAA-K5UgBpKA8f6MQFLXxLGjo-hlKAsbgQNbsCpfPDcSTATgobisdacXCcABeEBMhH2EKhEBhRG6aCwuAICBOAAoUAAjABWLD2AEoWKt1ltOLs-mQColPJk+EcggaMt5eGYThRafTGczWW0cFyeZoEPzIdDYSMZokZfKlb81csqVqdUc9QkikYvFkrTa6QymSyEGyOdzee69gKvSL7I5o-7FcrgxrNts3rrTdHDRb47akw7U06XZmPYLhVAavVGs1WuzuB0i4HVeQoIFmWwoDJgEti34RMkoAA6VcBqDlaicH6yxXL6tzFVo6jTiCzvcHwwuAP7gtzZfAFB1ADKS2fRt40pVeTMFS3O5vfVoyPFITxnOcFWXIC5mvPdoMMB8n1fd8LS-H8-1PYA8HYFlwMVCIKkkSckmAABGFxm3ZZ0MzdaVQMvYooApDZjE0L8DjKFUKAAem4qRiKgMiWEoXiT2oBiYw-cRRN-CgiO4KdgAAJgotNqNdeQEDoiR4MY5jWPkL9OJ4vj5MUpThJMsT8ijOZayyaS+NksySIAZlUlsaM07TxLvUImIgFjeXYnTbP8-Tgq4swuNElzBNcyzRLE3TJItRzrIk+y+HS5yBOAAAWDyqNbWj6L8vTAoMiAQp0MKKqCtiVQ46g4BYUilNc5qoDlFgACJ2tc3rjNivL8sSvixNapi8AAWzldZ0rEnrzQcqzkrq1LVqSk9MpW7KrLMIA)

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const t1 = serializeDates({
  createdAt: new Date(),
})
// const t1: {
//     createdAt: string;
// }

const t2 = serializeDates({
  updatedAt: new Date()
})
// const t2: {
//     updatedAt: string;
// }

const t3 = serializeDates({
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date()
})
// const t3: {
//     updatedAt: string;
//     createdAt: string;
// }

const t4 = serializeDates({
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
  a: 123,
  b: "123"
})
// const t4: {
//     a: number;
//     b: string;
//     updatedAt: string;
//     createdAt: string;
// }
```

---

On second thought, we can do better. Let's modify `Overwrite` to only override properties of `T` which actually exist on `T`.

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = (Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & Pick<U, Extract<keyof U, keyof T>>) extends infer O ? {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K]
} : never
```

Now we don't need function overloading anymore:

```
function serializeDates<
  T extends { updatedAt?: Date, createdAt?: Date }
>(obj: T): Overwrite<T, {updatedAt: string, createdAt: string}> { 
  const retObj: any = { ...obj };
  if (obj.createdAt) {
    retObj.createdAt = obj.createdAt.toISOString();
  }

  if (obj.updatedAt) {
    retObj.updatedAt = obj.updatedAt.toISOString();
  }

  return retObj as any;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwEIHtgAsBqcA2BXCBKAXigG8AoKKAbQGsIQAuKBYAJwEsA7AcwF0WcbiADcVKAGN2EOMAgATAILAWAETkRx1PGAWblqqBvniAvuIqhIsRAGEZBlSXIT6jFmy59BUYWIlpWXlDdU1zS2toeAQAVT0nYBdKandmVg4eASERbShdfRCVMNMKCworcGglHBwASW4wPGBsLmFgIlIY1AxsfEIoAB9bBAdgxWdhmPjCieBIqqgAeQA3CHYAdy55AB4AFQAaKFiAPhcACgAFTkk6faOAUQAPSXwFCB2GEBQAMyhDqBfX7HE5nABkUGutx2sUeTw4cEkwE+jGBsMBqL+e1BUAAlFAIPCINwFEQeD91ssoAB+VypADSUB4GO+fyWviWNHp-DKUBY3Aga3YFR+eG4SM4KG4rHWnFwnAAXhATIR9gSiSSiGR8gkisBqSUIEcgokDcZNFAzCdzigAEYAKxYe1xLFW6y2nF2ALIBUSnkyfGNjj1-u8vCt5CggSlbCgMmASwdORAySgADoM3b7Za8pw-jaHWmTXr8SlqHGIAnC8W5i4s0Xg3M08AUHUAMpLNsB3jnXF5MwVah5qAF+1p30lunl+OJscT2ukevzwzN1sdrth3v9wcV4B4djSmcOvxEfwRCqSGNJYAARhcCFl8qVKoQ5zLNdCUAFG3N8l7BzKXEKAAemAqQrygW8WEoUDy2oD9igyMNxFggcKEvbhY2AAAme9HxwRVlU0V8y2XRDv1-CBe0AkCwIwrDsOg2i4J1WZPy8LIULAtD6OvABmPC2gI59iLfQJG0-CiVX-CQyKMKTNGoswgNg3jIL4pjYLguTQ045i4IQowOL4LjLQvCDgAAFkEuVhKI+QSPE8ZJIgH9pNxACdF1OZ+VcyiZOoOAWBvbC+M8qBbRYAAiEK+KimjVIsyzNLAuCgq-PAAFtbXWUy4MipC9K08sdMKkz9PLQzdPK1CgA)

Comment: Wow amazing, I'm going to need some time to study this. Thanks!

Comment: @Sandy I updated my answer for a better solution